# How to get a numbered list renumbering when a value changes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 lists of numbers (col1 & col2) below.
I'd like to add 2 columns (col3 & col4) that do the following.
col3 numbers col2 starting at 1 every time col2 changes (e.g. from b2 to b3).
col4 is TRUE on the last occurrence for each value in col2.

The data is sorted by col1, then col2 to begin.
Note. values in col2 can occur for different values of col1. (i.e. I can have b1 for every value of col 1 (a, b, c))

I can get this working fine for ~5000 rows (~6 sec), but scaling to ~1 million rows it hangs up.

Here is my code

```
df$col3 <- 0
df$col4 <- FALSE
stopHere <- nrow(df)
c1 <- 'xxx'
c2 <- 'xxx'
for (i in 1:stopHere) {
  if (df[i, "col1"] != c1) {
    c2 <- 0
    c3 <- 1
    c1 <- df[i, "col1"]
  }
  if (df[i, "col2"] != c2) {
    df[i - 1, "col4"] <- TRUE
    c3 <- 1
    c2  <- df[i, "col2"]
  }
  df[i, "col3"] <- c3
  c3  <- c3 + 1
}
```

This is my desired output.

```
1     a   b1    1 FALSE
2     a   b1    2 FALSE
3     a   b1    3  TRUE
4     a   b2    1 FALSE
5     a   b2    2  TRUE
6     a   b3    1 FALSE
7     a   b3    2 FALSE
8     a   b3    3 FALSE
9     a   b3    4 FALSE
10    a   b3    5  TRUE
11    b   b1    1 FALSE
12    b   b1    2 FALSE
13    b   b1    3 FALSE
14    b   b1    4  TRUE
15    b   b2    1 FALSE
16    b   b2    2 FALSE
17    b   b2    3 FALSE
18    b   b2    4  TRUE
19    c   b1    1  TRUE
20    c   b2    1 FALSE
21    c   b2    2 FALSE
22    c   b2    3  TRUE
23    c   b3    1 FALSE
24    c   b3    2  TRUE
25    c   b4    1 FALSE
26    c   b4    2 FALSE
27    c   b4    3 FALSE
28    c   b4    4 FALSE
```

Comment: Fun question. Very simple, but there will be a wide variety of very interesting solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution that works for your sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = rep(letters[1:3], c(10, 8, 10)),
  V2 = rep(paste("b", c(1:3, 1:2, 1:4) ,sep=""), c(3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4))
  )
```

Create columns 3 and 4

```
zz <- rle(as.character(dat$V2))$lengths
dat$V3 <- sequence(zz)
dat$V4 <- FALSE
dat$V4[head(cumsum(zz), -1)] <- TRUE
```

The results:

```
dat
   V1 V2 V3    V4
1   a b1  1 FALSE
2   a b1  2 FALSE
3   a b1  3  TRUE
4   a b2  1 FALSE
5   a b2  2  TRUE
6   a b3  1 FALSE
7   a b3  2 FALSE
8   a b3  3 FALSE
9   a b3  4 FALSE
10  a b3  5  TRUE
11  b b1  1 FALSE
12  b b1  2 FALSE
13  b b1  3 FALSE
14  b b1  4  TRUE
15  b b2  1 FALSE
16  b b2  2 FALSE
17  b b2  3 FALSE
18  b b2  4  TRUE
19  c b1  1  TRUE
20  c b2  1 FALSE
21  c b2  2 FALSE
22  c b2  3  TRUE
23  c b3  1 FALSE
24  c b3  2  TRUE
25  c b4  1 FALSE
26  c b4  2 FALSE
27  c b4  3 FALSE
28  c b4  4 FALSE
```

Comment: I echo @BrianDiggs. Also love getting to use `cumsum` for stuff like this.

Comment: I also did not know `sequence`. How? But I concur.

Comment: WOW! Thanks! This is incredibly faster than what I was doing. Love the new tricks - sequence & rle.

Answer (score 6):

Some example data would be helpful. Nevertheless, this should be a good place to start. With 3 unique values in `col1`, and 4 in `col2`, it only takes a second for 10^6 rows:

```
n = 10^6

col1 = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), n, replace=T)
col2 = sample(paste('b', 1:4, sep=''), n, replace=T)

data = data.frame(col1, col2, col3=0, col4=FALSE)
data = data[do.call(order, data), ]

data$col3 = unlist(t(tapply(as.numeric(data$col2), data[,1:2], function(x) 1:length(x))))
data$col4[c(diff(data$col3), -1) < 0] = TRUE
```

Comment: Thx! I love it when I get to use the derivative trick for things like `col4`. Might be able to speed up the `col3` calculation with a bit more effort, but switching to `tapply` was at least a good place to start.

Comment: Your `col4` misses the transitions where `col2` resets upon changes to `col1`.  I think you need `!= 0` rather than `== 1` (any change, not just an increment)

Comment: @Andrie BTW I'm getting even faster performance if I combine your `col3` method with my `col4` method. :)

Comment: @BrianDiggs Nice catch. I just switched it to cue off the already-calculated `col3` instead.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the help. However, I think the last line should have `<=0`. If you have `<0`, you miss the case where there is only 1 element in `col2` before `col2` changes.

Answer (score 3):

First, make your starting data reproducible, and make `col1` and `col2` columns in a dataframe.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(
"a   b1
a   b1
a   b1
a   b2
a   b2
a   b3
a   b3
a   b3
a   b3
a   b3
b   b1
b   b1
b   b1
b   b1
b   b2
b   b2
b   b2
b   b2
c   b1
c   b2
c   b2
c   b2
c   b3
c   b3
c   b4
c   b4
c   b4
c   b4"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(dat) <- c("col1", "col2")
```

Run length encoding gives the lengths of your sequences, since everything is starting out sorted.

```
runs <- rle(dat$col2)
```

Now manipulate that info.  For each element in the length component, create a sequence of that length and put them all together.  The indicies of the `TRUE` values for `col4` can be gotten from the `cumsum` of the lengths.

```
dat$col3 <- unlist(sapply(runs$lengths, function(l) seq(length.out=l)))
dat$col4 <- FALSE
dat$col4[cumsum(runs$lengths)] <- TRUE
```

For the result:

```
> dat
   col1 col2 col3  col4
1     a   b1    1 FALSE
2     a   b1    2 FALSE
3     a   b1    3  TRUE
4     a   b2    1 FALSE
5     a   b2    2  TRUE
6     a   b3    1 FALSE
7     a   b3    2 FALSE
8     a   b3    3 FALSE
9     a   b3    4 FALSE
10    a   b3    5  TRUE
11    b   b1    1 FALSE
12    b   b1    2 FALSE
13    b   b1    3 FALSE
14    b   b1    4  TRUE
15    b   b2    1 FALSE
16    b   b2    2 FALSE
17    b   b2    3 FALSE
18    b   b2    4  TRUE
19    c   b1    1  TRUE
20    c   b2    1 FALSE
21    c   b2    2 FALSE
22    c   b2    3  TRUE
23    c   b3    1 FALSE
24    c   b3    2  TRUE
25    c   b4    1 FALSE
26    c   b4    2 FALSE
27    c   b4    3 FALSE
28    c   b4    4  TRUE
```

Note that the last line has `col4` `TRUE`, which matches your written description (last of a set is `TRUE`), but does not match your example output.  I don't know which you want.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Good catch. The last line should've had `col4` `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't need any loops, nor `rle` or other clever functions; just mere `merge` and `aggregate` functions.

Preparing your data (used Andrie's code) first:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(letters[1:3], c(10, 8, 10)),
  y = rep(paste("b", c(1:3, 1:2, 1:4) ,sep=""), c(3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4))
)
```

**The solution:**

```
minmax <- with(df, merge(
                aggregate(seq(x), by = list(x = x, y = y), min),
                aggregate(seq(x), by = list(x = x, y = y), max)
          ))

names(minmax)[3:4] = c("min", "max") # unique pairs with min/max global order

result <- with(merge(df, minmax), 
    data.frame(x, y, count = seq(x) - min + 1, last = seq(x) == max))
```

This solution assumes that the input is sorted as you said, but can be easily modified to work on unsorted tables (and keep them unsorted).